# Spring - Is it possible to remove Spring MVC and have only session management and Authentication in web project

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I want to write a web application (Spring based) which uses spring session and spring-security only. I do not want any MVC endpoint. Is it possible to have spring web application without MVC which only has an authentication provider and session management.

This is because I am writing a authenticaiton service which just check if user session is valid or invalid. In case of invalid throw http 401 status and incase session is valid respond with http 200.

Answer (score -1):

Spring offers an `@EnableAuthorizationServer` which can handle your purpose. Maybe this example can help you: http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs

Part 2 describes how you can set up your Authorization Server with oAuth2.